# Creating a pseudo AI regarding the "hat of balls" in Python3.3

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a python project currently to create a game similar to pick up sticks, and I have come to a confusing point.  I have created a list of lists, stickList, and I want to grab one of the values ([1, 2, 3]) and decrement a variable using it.  Here is the code I am currently using:

If I have 30 sticksOnBoard I want the computer to grab 1, 2, or 3 sticks, decrement the sticks on the board by that number, and then have the loop pick up from there with the user.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong though sadly, because the sticksOnBoard -= stickList(ballPick) isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want what I think you want, then what you want is the `random` module.

If you're using a list's length to determine your choices, you'll want to make sure that the choices are in range of the list. Fortunately using the `range()` feature does this automatically, so by getting the `len()` of the list before indexing, you'll never fail.

```
import random
my_choices = range(0, len(some_list))
print random.choice(my_choices)
```

EDIT: Ah, perhaps you're seeing the selection is out of range? Setting `sticksOnBoard` to the length of your list will cause an `IndexError`.

```
>>> mylist = [x for x in range(0, 16)] #this list will have items 0 through 15, for a total of 16
>>> mylist[16] #this is 1 too large for the list, however
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If you always want the last item in the list, you can use `mylist.pop()` to always **remove** the last item in the list. If you're looping over a list, this could cause problems.

You can also index by using `mylist[-1]`, which will always index the very last item in the list.

Comment: 'code'(ai_choices = (1, 2, 3)
                ballPick = random.choice(ai_choices)
                move -= stickList[sticksOnBoard][ballPick]
                sticksOnBoard -= move
                move = 0)

Comment: Perhaps you can post the kind of error you're seeing, then? You haven't included an error message, just that it "isn't working".

Comment: I am getting a list index out of range on the line with move -= stickList[sticksOnBoard][ballPick]

Comment: I want it ideally to look at the list of lists - and access the list at [sticksOnBoard][ballPick]  For example if there are 23 sticks left, I want to go to the 23rd list and then use the random.choice to grab 1 2 or 3.

Comment: Ok, so you need to use a valid number for your index. Remember that if you're indexing a list you need to choose between 0 and `len(list) - 1`. See the second half of my answer for the `IndexError` comments

Comment: I have read your comment but I'm not very good at this.  If this is running in a loop, wouldn't I need to use a variable to access my list?  You are correct though, when I use ints instead of variables it does index.  Why aren't those variables (which are ints) working?                 ballPick = int(random.choice(ai_choices))
                move -= stickList[sticksOnBoard][ballPick]

Comment: You need a variable, but you need to know that `some_list[0]` is always the first item, NOT `some_list[1]`. So if you have 30 items in a list, the last one will be at `some_list[29]`, NOT `some_list[30]`. Your second list would be the same; the valid indexes for that list will be between `0` and `2`.

Comment: Ah I see, so the sticksOnBoard variable is too high?

Comment: I believe all of the above are too high. I've edited my answer to show you how to dynamically ensure you're making the right choices - get the length of the list before producing your random choice, and use `range(0, len(some_list))` to ensure your choices are never out of range

Comment: What about this?                 ai_choices = (0, 1, 2)
                ballPick = int(random.choice(ai_choices))
                move = stickList[sticksOnBoard - 1][ballPick]

Comment: You could do that -- BUT, if you KNOW that you always just want the very last item in the list, don't bother with subtraction! Just use `stickList[-1]`, which will always reference the last item in the list, regardless of its size.